# What is a better way to calculate rolling metrics that spans over batches in Spark structured streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm consuming events from an Event Hub on Azure and want to calculate metrics that are not based on single events, but from pairs of events. I've found plenty of information on how to deal with aggregates but not so much sequence dependent measures (lead, lag for example). I understand that there are no such out-of-the-box features in Spark Streaming.

**Assumptions to scope the problem:**

1. Events from the devices I'm receiving are appearing in the right order. Out of two messages sent from the same device, the one with greater offset denotes the most recent event.
2. There are more unique devices than there are partitions in the event hub (i.e. a sequence of messages on a partition cannot be assumed to belong to the same device

**Objective:**

To be able to calculate lead and lag columns for all messages on a batch basis, i.e. only calculate it on the new delta arriving.

```
+---------+-----------------+--------+-----------+------------+
| batchId | deviceReference | offset | lagOffset | leadOffset |
+---------+-----------------+--------+-----------+------------+
|     100 | a               |      1 | null      | 3          |
|     100 | b               |      2 | null      | 5          |
|     100 | a               |      3 | 1         | 6          |
|     200 | c               |      4 | null      | 7          |
|     200 | b               |      5 | 2         | null       |
|     300 | a               |      6 | 3         | null       |
|     300 | c               |      7 | 4         | null       |
+---------+-----------------+--------+-----------+------------+
```

lagOffset and leadOffset are the columns I want to calculate and batchId is the identifier of the events consumed from the Event Hub at a given time. Obviously, without accessing the previous and next offset for a deviceReference, the first and last record in each batchId would have lag- and leadOffset null, so I figured I'd give caching a go.

**An attempt**

> Create empty DF and persist (only if first time run, otherwise cache exists)

```
if (!positionCacheExists)
  spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], batchCacheSchema)
    .write
    .partitionBy("deviceReference")
    .format("json")
    .mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Append)
    .save(batchCachePath)
```

> Create window functions to use for lead/lag calculation and to use to exclude last record (as it will lack lead value and will be persisted in the next batch (if the lead has arrived).

```
    val w = Window.partitionBy("deviceReference").orderBy(desc("offset"))
    val leadLag = Window.partitionBy("deviceReference").orderBy("offset")
```

> Process stream

```
  incomingDeviceStream.writeStream
                      .foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>

                            //empty if first time, otherwise contains the second latest events per device from previous batch
                            val batchCache = spark.read.schema(lastBatchSchema).format("json").load(positionCachePath)
                            val modBatch = batchDF.withColumn("maxRow", rank().over(w))

                            modBatch.join(batchCache, 
                                          modBatch("deviceReference")===batchCache("deviceReference") &&
                                          modBatch("offset")>batchCache("offset"))
                                  .withColumn("last", batchCache("offset"))
                                  .union(modBatch.join(batchCache,
                                          modBatch("deviceReference")===batchCatche("deviceReference"),
                                          "left_anti")
                                  .withColumn("last", lit(null)))
                                  .withColumn("lagOffset", coalesce(lag(col("offset"),1).over(leadLag), col("last")).as("lagOffset"))
                                  .withColumn("leadOffset", lead(col("offset"),1).over(leadLag).as("leadOffset"))
                                  .filter(col("maxRow")>1)
                                  .write
                                  .partitionBy("deviceReference")
                                  .format("parquet")
                                  .mode(Append)
                                  .save(deviceEventPath)

                            //Store the second latest event per device as the last will have null as lead and will be set when the next event comes
                            modBatch.filter(col("maxRow")===2)
                                  .write
                                  .partitionBy("deviceReference")
                                  .format("json")
                                  .mode(Overwrite)
                                  .save(batchCachePath)
                                       }
                      .trigger(Trigger.Once())
                      .start()
                      .awaitTermination()
```

**Reflections:**

- This feels very brittle and akward as if I mess up the state in the batchCache DF, I will have a mess. I would have liked to use the builtin features as checkpoints, but I can't figure out how to make them work for me when I need to change the batch scope to exclude the last record per device.
- Obviously I could apply the lead lag to the target table of the streaming job, but that make the calculations much bigger, redundant and it would also introduce updates to the data unless the last record per device is cut off (the one where lead is null).

**Questions:**

- I think I'm missing something big here. Finding the neighbour events for an event is very important for measures I want to calculate, and I am sure I'm not the only one. If all devices had their own partitions I guess the problem would be solved, but since the sharding mechanism in the Event Hub is hashing I don't know how that could be enforced. Can someone please tell me if I'm attacking this in the wrong place?

  - If I'm not attacking this in the wrong place, what Spark features am I not using that I should be using to make this more robust?

Cheers,